# File upload issue in ie11

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am using a file upload plugin in my application, but the actual file name user selected using the browser  button is behaving differently in IE 10 and IE 11

```
<input type="file" name="testFile" id="testapiFile">
```

I am submitting the form using jquery form submit method.

In the network tab I am seeing the file name going as the full path (C:\fullpath\test.doc), but in server side, for IE 10, i am getting as **test.doc** and in IE11 **C:fullpathtest.doc** (getting an invalid path name)

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Prats

Comment: What does your server side look like?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/20/rtm-platform-changes.aspx has some more context. The `C:\Fakepath\ ` stuff is only ever seen by JavaScript (it's not uploaded to the server) which means that you probably have JavaScript code on the client which is sending the `.value` property of the control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help - perhaps the security settings in IE11 are different?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. When a file is selected by using the input type=file object, the value of the value property depends on the value of the "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" security setting for the security zone used to display the Web page containing the input object. For more information, see value.

Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later. By default, Internet Explorer does not include folder or directory path information when uploading files to sites in the Restricted zone. This improves security by preventing information disclosure. Also, to improve accessibility, the input type=file element now contains two accessible elements—one for the input box and one for the Browse button. This change is applicable only to accessibility tools; script implementations are not affected.

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! There is an IE parameter that could modify the "perception" of the site : Internet Options / Security / Local Intranet / Sites. If i check the first one, IE will detect http://localhost:8080 as an Internet website and full path will not be included. But if I check the 3 others, it will be considered as "Intranet" and the full path will be included (with default settings for "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" in each zone)